# server sent events: how to detect client disconnection from Node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, events, server-sent-events

I've setup a simple server-sent-event for testing which sends data periodically once client gets connected. When client reloads the page or move to another page, browser closes the connection and stops receiving the events.

```
app.get("/stream", (req, res) =>{
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });

  const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data/group_list.json"))

  let i = 0;
  
  const intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    ++i;
    console.log('iteration', i);

    if ( i === 5 ) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        res.end();
        return 1
    }
    res.write('data:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n\n');
    res.flush();
  }, 3000);
})
```

Here's my event handler in React.

```
    handleSSE = () => {
        console.log('here');
        const url = "/test/stream"
        //url can be your server url

        if ('EventSource' in window) {
            let source = new EventSource(url)

            source.onopen = (e) => console.log('cnx successful', e);
            source.onmessage = (e) => console.log('data-', JSON.parse(e.data));
            source.onerror = (e) => {
                console.log('cnx failed', e);
                source.close();
            };
        }
    }
```

The SSE only stops emitting the data once "i" reaches a certain number, I'd like the SSE to detect & stop emitting data when client closes the connection. what I specifically need is a way for setInterval() in my server to stop when the client closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

when you get a new request from your `client` to your `server`, you can add an event listener on the `request` object.

This would trigger when the client closes the connection, so your can handle it in your server :
:

```
// on your express route
request.on("close", () => {
// YOUR LOGIC HERE
});
```

For me it's removing the client request from an in-memory list and tearing down other dependencies it had

Comment: except it doesn't get called, at least in my case. In my case it is being called only when the server closes the connection, but not when it's the client closing it (I'm using [Fetch Event Source](https://github.com/Azure/fetch-event-source) in the client and closing it with the abort signal). Got any quick advice to add to your answer for me or I better post a new question?

Comment: hmm why/when does the server closes the connection ? request.on("close"..) handler should fire when the client is the one that closes the connection

Comment: In my case the server closes the connection by design after some time it has been kept open (15 minutes or 24 hours depending on the specific SSE endpoint). I could scratch that to be honest, but as of now it's the only thing that cleans things up from time to time.

Comment: trying my luck, maybe it's related to your library you are using ? 
try using the 'eventsource' package and see if the request.close handler does something on the server side

Comment: I tried switching to the native EventSource but I got the same behavior. I then realized the problem is likely somewhere in the Ionic/Angular proxy I use during development (proxy in `ionic.config.json`), because if I compile my webapp and delploy it to a real server, it mostly works (mostly because SSE connection close events are being fired with some delay on the server, maybe one minute delay or so, but better that than nothing).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Have you tried it? Is there documentation supporting this?

Comment: In case any of you is still trying to find a solution, I managed to fix this by adding the listener to the response object, rather than the request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77765137/2229362

Answer (score 0):

To react to a client disconnecting from an SSE (EventSource) Stream, the solution that worked for me was listening to the `close` event on the `response`, rather than the `request`:

```js
// in the express route
response.on("close", () => {
// disconnect logic here
});
```

This is using express 4.17.21.
Similar to the comments in the [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053701/2229362) adding the listener to the request did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add windows unload event inside handleSSE function for check the connection.

For that you need to add Event Listener of beforeunload inside handleSSE function.

So your final handleSSE function will be:

```
handleSSE = () => {
  console.log('here');
  const url = "/test/stream"
  //url can be your server url

  if ('EventSource' in window) {
    let source = new EventSource(url)

    source.onopen = (e) => console.log('cnx successful', e);
    source.onmessage = (e) => console.log('data-', JSON.parse(e.data));
    source.onerror = (e) => {
      console.log('cnx failed', e);
      source.close();
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
      if (source.readyState !== EventSource.CLOSED) {
        source.close();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, what I specifically need is a way for setInterval in my server to stop when the  client closes the connection.